# First message sent to my chatbot hangs on loading screen

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I've created a Facebook messenger bot that works great. The problem is in a new conversation the first time a user selects the bot to open a chat, they are stuck on an endless loading screen. I've tried adding and removing greeting messages via the api makes no difference. 
Any tips on debugging this would be helpful.

Comment: On which platform do you or users experience endless loading screen? Is your app up to date?

Comment: Facebook messenger. I'm setting the greeting with the latest API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an open bug on facebook's side that's causing this bug.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1863035593948757/

The work around is to use the search to initiate a conversation not compose.